# SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word in Python script

Tags: python

I get the following strange stack error when trying to run my Python script:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import simplejso
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Why is `import` an unexpected key word?

Comment: The slew of *`node.js`* errors and the fact that the traceback looks nothing like Python didn't tip you off?

Answer (score 4):

Check your terminal. You're probably running `node` instead of `python`.